# Why is my variable returning a None value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://pastebin.com/BExAC7rJ   `new_pass = print(str(encrypt(original_pass)))`

I put my code in a pastebin because I'm stupid and can't format big chunks of code using this website.
The code is a very basic encrypter. I need to know why when I try print the variable "new_pass" (which is the encrypted password) it just prints as "None".

```py
#simple password encrypter
def encrypt(phrase):
    encryption = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "Aa":
            encryption = encryption + "g"
        elif letter in "Bb":
            encryption = encryption + "r"
        elif letter in "Cc":
            encryption = encryption + "q"
        elif letter in "Dd":
            encryption = encryption + "f"
        elif letter in "Ee":
            encryption = encryption + "z"
        elif letter in "Ff":
            encryption = encryption + "n"
        elif letter in "Gg":
            encryption = encryption + "a"
        elif letter in "Hh":
            encryption = encryption + "v"
        elif letter in "Ii":
            encryption = encryption + "m"
        elif letter in "Jj":
            encryption = encryption + "x"
        elif letter in "Kk":
            encryption = encryption + "s"
        elif letter in "Ll":
            encryption = encryption + "o"
        elif letter in "Mm":
            encryption = encryption + "c"
        elif letter in "Nn":
            encryption = encryption + "u"
        elif letter in "Oo":
            encryption = encryption + "i"
        elif letter in "Pp":
            encryption = encryption + "l"
        elif letter in "Qq":
            encryption = encryption + "w"
        elif letter in "Rr":
            encryption = encryption + "b"
        elif letter in "Ss":
            encryption = encryption + "e"
        elif letter in "Tt":
            encryption = encryption + "p"
        elif letter in "Uu":
            encryption = encryption + "r"
        elif letter in "Vv":
            encryption = encryption + "h"
        elif letter in "Ww":
            encryption = encryption + "y"
        elif letter in "Xx":
            encryption = encryption + "d"
        elif letter in "Yy":
            encryption = encryption + "j"
        elif letter in "Zz":
            encryption = encryption + "g"
        elif letter in "1":
            encryption = encryption + "6"
        elif letter in "2":
            encryption = encryption + "1"
        elif letter in "3":
            encryption = encryption + "5"
        elif letter in "4":
            encryption = encryption + "2"
        elif letter in "5":
            encryption = encryption + "10"
        elif letter in "6":
            encryption = encryption + "7"
        elif letter in "7":
            encryption = encryption + "9"
        elif letter in "8":
            encryption = encryption + "3"
        elif letter in "9":
            encryption = encryption + "8"
        elif letter in "0":
            encryption = encryption + "4"
    return encryption

original_pass = input("Enter raw password: ")
new_pass = print(str(encrypt(original_pass)))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The print function returns doesn't return anything. So new_pass will be None. Remove the print function from the line and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to print variable, Use :

```
new_pass = str(encrypt(original_pass))
```

Comment: I changed it and now I can also save the encryption to files. TYSM

Answer (score 0):

You did:

```
new_pass = print(str(encrypt(original_pass)))
```

That assigns what *print* returns to `new_pass`, and `print` always returns `None`. Make it:

```
new_pass = encrypt(original_pass)
print(new_pass)
```

The function is already returning a `str`, so I removed the `str()` wrapping.